# What exactly is the last parameter on this PostMessage code for?

Tags: c#-5.0

```
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, vk, 0x11480001);
```

What is the last code on this mean the 0x11480001 what is the purpose of that number?

Comment: *0x11480001* is not valid in vb.net

Comment: [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Here is the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Sorry I listed it under vb.net instead of C# my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The *vk* is for *Virtual-Key Codes* and the last 4 byte value contains lot of informations. Depends which bits you want to `isolate` eg the 30th bit

```
( (0x11480001 & 0x400000000) >> 30 )
```

is *The previous key state*

[WM_KEYDOWN message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I know what the vk is its just a reference to a constant. I asked about the last number after vk. What is the purpose of it and what is that number exactly. 0x11480001

Comment: @FrostByte And i did answer. You don't use it as whole but get the actual bits in it. Those bits have special meaning as the 30th one i said as an example

Comment: I guess I don't understand it then. Every time I search google for C# PostMessage everyone that posts an example uses that code at the end. I was just wondering why it has to be there.